# I got "EmptyDrop" to get the specific object of a collection (Shopify)

Tags: frontend, shopify, e-commerce, storefront, shopify-liquid

I have the collection **"Healthy Products"**:

[image]

Then, with **Liquid**, I'm trying to get the object of the collection **"Healthy Products"** with this code below:

```js
{{ collections["Healthy Products"] }}
```

But I got **"EmptyDrop"**:

[image]

Are there anything wrong to my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put **"-"(Hyphen)** between **"Healthy"** and **"Products"** as shown below:

```js
{{ collections["Healthy-Products"] }}
```

Then, you can get **"CollectionDrop"**:

[image]

And, in convention, **lowercase** is used in Shopify:

```js
{{ collections["healthy-products"] }}
```